# Can we use apex method in formula field?

Tags: apex, email, formula-field

So i surfed a lot regarding this it but didn't found much relevant info,

**Reference**

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wdyIAA

[Can I store my block of apex code as formula field and execute in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/can-i-store-my-block-of-apex-code-as-formula-field-and-execute-in-apex)

I want to know that can we use apex method in formula field to populate the same depending upon what apex method returns ?

so lets consider I have a `global class` and `global method` named as below respectively

`emailProvider.getEmail(String a)`

That takes a `field value`(Name) as an argument and returns `email` based on the argument

I want to use it as a formula field > `emailProvider.getEmail(Custom_field__c)`.

I tried but getting error as `Error: Unknown function emailProvider.getEmail Check spelling.`

**Note**

Now i know we can use formula for this instead of using Apex method but, (Custom_Field__c) is already a CASE formula which calls for even another CASE formula hence broke the limit.

I would really appreciate any help

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use Apex in a formula field.

Formula fields are stored and evaluated in the database engine(s) that Salesforce uses in the background (which unless something has changed, is a combination of Oracle, HBase, and a few other things that I forget).

The database itself cannot run Apex (and I suspect it can't access the compiled JVM bytecode for a given Apex class either), so it cannot use Apex in its formulas.